# report viewer not working when published

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I get the error

> An error occurred during local report processing.
>
> The definition of the report 'Reports\REpersAccDet.rdlc' is invalid.
>
> An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: did you copy over the assemblies or install the redistributable files for report viewer on the server you are publishing to?

Comment: i manually upload the reports and download the dll package from nuget cause it didn't found on the server

Comment: perhaps you could create a folder in your project solution called `Lib` and copy the .dlls there also set the copy local = true, and remove the existing references and re-add them pointing to the `Lib` folder this way you don't have to worry about `GAC` the .dlls..

Comment: you need to install the SQL types distributable on the server. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065

Comment: Which ***Visual Studio*** _versión_ you use? `ASP.NET version`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMIIW,

What I do in publishing an app which has report viewer, is installing report viewer redistributable package on your published computer (e.g server or client computer). It depends on your IDE version.

If you use VS 2010, then you must install 2010 package (download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442)).

If you use greater version (VS2012+), there two files you must install.

1. Report viewer 2012 runtime (download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747))
2. SQLSysClrTypes (for x86 download [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239643&clcid=0x409), for x64 download [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239644&clcid=0x409))

Hope it can solve your problem.

Comment: my IDE vs 2013 the server is win server 2012 sql 2014 i download all you said but still the same problem '

Comment: have you set the report file property to 'copy always' or 'copy if newer'?

Comment: it work i change it to 'Copy if newer'  thank you :D